# mongodb document insertion crashes with size error 8mb

Tags: php, mongodb, size, domdocument

I am inserting an array in MongoDb using php .First i was getting error that max limit is 16 MB. Now i am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'document fragment is too large: 8516075, max: 8388608'.
```

Please Explain this and the wayaround of this

Comment: Code or it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

you need to beak the file in pieces that fit in the memory... This way you whill avoid this error. And send the information to the other end.

Comment: can you please tell me in detail. i have quite a big nested array

Comment: I can't do you work! I just can help. And this is the solution to your problem.